# can we force to open facebook link in browser not in native app iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to force through your application that it will open the web link in safari only not in native app like facebook, twitter or web view etc. 
So far i searched found only this code that is used for opening the link

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.facebook.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But what can we paste in else there below?

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:nsurl]){
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:nsurl];
}
else {
    //Open the url as usual, but how?
}
```

Comment: Have you encountered the control in else condition in any case or you just want it to be fail safe?

Comment: Tried else condition also and used the same way in else as in if, but output was same.

Comment: @channi Do you have any idea or answer or just want to query?

Comment: I am looking for answer as well but yes it is also a query

Answer (score 1):

Use http://facebook.com/ instead of `www.facebook.com`
this will force a link to open in Safari instead of native app*

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com/"];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:myURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a webView to open any link of your choice.

Comment: I clearly mentioned that my requirement is to open in safari only not in the webview